# MultipartHttpServletRequest getting file content but not form ID

Tags: java, spring

I have an html form to submit like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formToSubmit" action="/create_components" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="component_1" id="component_1">

    Other inputs here...
```

On the server side, I wanna get all the inputs (both files and text inputs)... and the form is dynamically created so I don't know in advance the name of the IDs.

On the server I need both content and IDs.

On the server I first tried to loop on the parameters, but this skip the inputs that are of type file and return only the text ones:

```
Enumeration<?> enums = request.getParameterNames();

while (enums.hasMoreElements()) {
  Object inputName = enums.nextElement();

  // Here I get all the input that are not files

}
```

Then I tried in that way:

```
 MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;

 Set set = multipartRequest.getFileMap().entrySet(); 
 Iterator i = set.iterator(); 

 while(i.hasNext()) { 
     Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next(); 
     String fileName = (String)me.getKey();
     MultipartFile multipartFile = (MultipartFile)me.getValue();
     byte[] bytes = multipartFile.getBytes();

 }
```

In this way I actually get the files, but I don't know how to get their IDs.

I need both: the file content and the ID (in this example "component_1"). How can I do that? Is there a way I can change the last code in order to get also the ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the name of file by calling to:

```
String valueOfNameAttribute = ((MultipartFile)me.getValue()).getName()
```

Isn't that what you need?

Comment: No, I don't need the name of the file. I just need the ID of the form and content

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to have value of "id="component_1"  on the server side? This is not possible as far as I know. The id is only used on client side. Only the value of "name" attribute of the <input> tag is sent to server.

Comment: yeah, name... that's correct. I can set name and id with the same value on the client side

Comment: @user1883212 The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html) says that `getName()` will "Return the name of the parameter in the multipart form." so sounds like it does exactly what you want. It doesn't return the filename of the uploaded file.

Comment: @user1883212 as Anthony said this is exactly what you need, you will access "component_1" by calling `((MultipartFile)me.getValue()).getName()`. No more no less.

Comment: yeah, getname() returns the name in the form. That's why I had been mislead. That's not the name of the file. Thanks.